# eventbus listen to $on can't be executed vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-bus

I am trying to use eventbus to send and get data from different components.I have created a global variable eventbus and in each component when i want to send data to a specific component I write this

```
eventBus.$emit('dis',this.displaytype);
```

and in this specific component I wrote:

```
eventBus.$on('dis', function (snippet) {
    this.displaydis = snippet
    console.log('display: ', this.displaydis)
  }.bind(this));
```

I have written this in created hook but this code is not executing.Can any one help me ?

Comment: What error message are your receiving in the console of your browser?

Comment: Nothing is shown on the console i don't khow even what to do or what's the problem

Comment: How are you importing your eventBus? Perhaps this article can help you out: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: thnx so much  ,i do exactly like the article i can't figure out what's the problem

Comment: Why don't you set up a JSFiddle where you simply try to set up an eventBus. If you run into problems with your JSFiddle I can help you out with debugging.

Comment: thnks so much ok i will try it